# Bootstrap 3 CenterNav In the Middle of a page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="other center_2">
    <div class="container_2">
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#work" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</div>


.centered_2 {
  position: fixed; /* or absolute */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

http://shearelegancechicago.com/todd/

I'm trying to center the nav right dab smack in the middle when it opens up. I tried a fewed different tutorials nothing is working. The live link is including.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS you have `.centered_2` class - and in HTML you have `center_2`. Just change to `center_2` in CSS and everything will work fine!

```css
.center_2 {
  position: fixed; /* or absolute */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="other center_2">
    <div class="container_2">
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#work" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bqmmytwL).

Comment: @VeliborNikolic glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this.

```
.sidebar-nav {
/* position: absolute; */ No use.
width: 250px;
margin: 0 auto; /*Set the margin as per your requirement. eg; 50px auto 0px*/
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
border: 1px solid red; /*just to highlight*/
}
```

Hope this help you.!